# iphone Power on 3G radios using url request not working

Tags: iphone

using sdk 3.1.2 on iphone

I am using the following code to activate the 3G connection but it doesn't seem
to be working, anyone know what i need to do

NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:                            [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:                                            [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]] delegate:self];
                        [conn cancel];

Comment: What do you mean by "activate the 3G connection"? Also, **accept some answers**. You've received 14 answers to your 10 questions and have accepted zero of them. That's rude.

Comment: Hi,  I am sorry i didn't realise about accepting the answers.

i mean power on the radios as they power off every so often. If using Reachability its the situation where WWAN is reachable but a connection is required so i tried requesting a connection as above and  then cancel straight away but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you calling:

```
[conn cancel];
```

Shouldn't you do:

```
[conn start];
```

or something that actually tries to open the connection?